# Access the elements of a model in the view from a CListView

Tags: yii

Sorry for this question. I have read two books and several tutorials, and the documentation of Yii, but I still can't understand how to do this very basic thing. Basically, I need to read all the elements from a table and display them in a list.

I did this

On the controller (method actionIndex())

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();

    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Items', array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));

    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
```

On the view index.php

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'itemView' => '_item'
```

));

?>

On the view item.php

```
<?php $this->renderPartial('_item',array(
        'post'=>$dataProvider,

    )); ?>
```

and in the partial view _item

```
<?php
$this->Widget('CMarkdown', array('purifyOutput'=>true));
```

?>

Even if the pagination works, the system doesn't show anything. I believe that must to exist some way to access, in the render view, to an object that has the elements of the current ActiveRecord element or something (I don't understand if the CActiveDataProvider of the controller is a ActiveRecord element or not).

I will really appreciate everyone who can help me in this matter

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you've said, it seems like you have an unnecessary file. You don't need item.php.

Also, your partial view _item needs to be:

```
$this->beginWidget('CMarkdown', array('purifyOutput'=>true));
echo $data->content;
$this->endWidget();
```

I wrote $data->content; but you need to replace the word content with the attribute you actually want displayed.